# How to get the selected date of a MonthCalendar control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

How to get the selected date of a MonthCalendar control in C# (Window forms)

Comment: Really good tutorial on youtube click [HERE for tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMLc5ewhAx8)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

"Just set the `MaxSelectionCount` to 1 so that users cannot select more than one day. Then in the `SelectionRange.Start.ToString()`. There is nothing available to show the selection of only one day." - Justin Etheredge

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/af4d5f2a-c00d-46de-8f25-c0a09f6bf2f9).

Comment: the Property is MonthCalendar.SelectionRange not 'SelectedRange' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionrange.start(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 11):

I just noticed that if you do:

```
monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString()
```

you will get only the date (e.g. `1/25/2014`) from a `MonthCalendar` control.

It's opposite to:

```
monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString()

//The OUTPUT will be (e.g. 1/25/2014 12:00:00 AM)
```

Because these `MonthCalendar` properties are of type **DateTime**. See the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the methods available to convert to a String representation. Also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may help to convert from a String to a DateTime object where applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Using `SelectionRange` you will get the `Start` and `End` date.

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    var startDate = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
    var endDate = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
}
```

If you want to update the maximum number of days that can be selected, then set `MaxSelectionCount` property. The default is 7.

```
// Only allow 21 days to be selected at the same time.
monthCalendar1.MaxSelectionCount = 21;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still trying, this link helped me out, too; it just puts it all together:

http://dotnetslackers.com/VB_NET/re-36138_How_To_Get_Selected_Date_from_MonthCalendar_control.aspx

```
private void MonthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
//Display the dates for selected range
Label1.Text = "Dates Selected from :" + (MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start() + " to " + MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End);

//To display single selected of date
//MonthCalendar1.MaxSelectionCount = 1;

//To display single selected of date use MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start/ MonthCalendarSelectionRange.End
Label2.Text = "Date Selected :" + MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start;
}
```

Comment: Fix this line: "MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start()". Because Start is a Property and can't be used as a Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.selectionrange.start(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It'll be helpful if you want just to convert it by:

```java
String myCalendar = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString()
```

But if you want to get a formatted output you could instead:

```java
String myCalendar = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

It's important to use year and day as lower caps, and month as upper or else it'll return you a wrong format, for example, if you do:

```java
String myCalendar = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

it will return: `YYYY-07-DD`   (If the original date's month was July)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow and thanks for contributing! To make your posts easier to read, you can add [markdown syntax](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/) to change the formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
    string clickeddate = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString("dddd, dd MMM yyyy");
    richTextBox.AppendText(clickeddate); //or whatever you decide to do with it. 
    }
```

Comment: MaxSelectionCount does not matter. Above is a working code.

Comment: Sure, and there are more answers not using it. This answer doesn't add anything new. You should post the comment only under the answer you intended to target here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33293422)

Answer (score -2):

[SelectionRange property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xah4ckt.aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @oleksii Please try to understand the answer before choosing the review comment template. The *essential parts of the answer* are right there in the link title. And I'm not exactly linking to a random blog post, but to the manufacturer's (*Microsoft's*) documentation.

Comment: @DanielBeck It's still important to ensure that answers on SO are stand alone.  Links within them should be supplementary to the answer, not *be* the answer.  This could mean quoting or summarizing relevant sections of the link, or just posting the link as a comment.  It's not just to prevent against broken links, it's also to prevent giving people looking for answers the run-around.  Nothing is more frustrating when you are linked to an answer, which links to an answer, which links to an answer, which actually has what you want.

Comment: @Servy I understand that. The link is optional though, as Microsoft's documentation, while possibly helpful, doesn't add anything substantial that would be missing here: *The key property of the MonthCalendar control is SelectionRange, the range of dates selected in the control.* I simply cannot imagine what could be added here that actually provides value and doesn't just circumvent the crap queue. Sample code? `var range = myMonthControl.SelectionRange;` doesn't look too helpful. Quoting from MSDN is redundant and too easily out of date. What else is there, other than filler text?

Comment: @Servy Thanks for taking the time to comment, by the way.