# how can i select date from MonthCalendar in vb.net 2012

Tags: vb.net

i would like to select date from month calender in vb.net

i need to select different date for (ex: 6/11/2014) and get it then work with it
in my case i can select just the current date (6/3/2014), i used the code bellow so anyone can advise???

```
Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateChanged(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs)
Handles MonthCalendar1.DateChanged
Dim str As String
str = MonthCalendar1.TodayDate.ToString 
MsgBox(str)
End Sub
```

any update will be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you seen [How to get the selected date of a MonthCalendar control in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429128/how-to-get-the-selected-date-of-a-monthcalendar-control-in-c-sharp)? It's in C#, but the basics are the same.

Comment: if you are just trying to pick a date, not a range, why not the `DateTimePicker`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub calMonth_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles calMonth.DateSelected

Dim sMonthSelected As String 'I have this under my Public class

    sMonthSelected = calMonth.SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    MsgBox(sMonthSelected) ' or whaterver output you require

End Sub
```